# While joining 2 mysql tables how to get only the required related row in second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following **2 tables A and B** in **MySQL** db. When I join the 2 tables by the VisitID (A.VisitID = B.VisitID) I want to pickup only the records that related the **latest Actiondateandtime** from the table B for a VisitID. For example for VisitID = 85 I want to pickup the row with 15/10/2014 3:44 in table B. For VisitID = 86 I only want to pickup the row with 09/10/2014 1:28 in table B.

Table A :

```
VisitID       VisitTitle                     VisitSummary                        Conclusion

85            Go to Paddy Field 1            Checked Temperatures                1
86            Soil Quality Checked           Checked PHP of different soil       2
87            Go to Paddy Field 2            Collected Soil samples              0
```

Table B:

```
RefID   VisitID      ActionDesc                                 Actiondateandtime

1       85           Submiited to Management                    9/10/2014  12:03
2       86           Sent to lab                                9/10/2014  1:06
3       86           Sent to lab                                9/10/2014  1:07
4       86           Sent to lab                                9/10/2014  1:21
5       86           Sent to lab                                9/10/2014  1:28
6       87           Followed with Soil scientist               9/10/2014  1:32
7       87           Followed with Soil scientist               9/10/2014  1:33
8       85           Submitted to Management                    15/10/2014 3:44
```

I want the result after the join of these 2 tables

```
A.VisitID  A.VisitTitle           A.Conclusion  B.RefID   B.VisitID  B.Actiondateandtime

85         Go to Paddy Field 1    1             8         85         15/10/2014 3:44
86         Soil Quality Checked   2             5         86         9/10/2014 1:28
87         Go to Paddy Field 2    0             7         87         9/10/2014 1:33
```

What MySQL code needed to get this required result?

Comment: `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` subquery

Comment: Hi PM-77 When we use by GROUP BY what code do we need to use to get the last Actiondateandtime related full row?.Thanks

Comment: last = `MAX(your_date)`

Answer (score 0):

try this.....

```
select *
from Table At1
inner join TableB t2 on t1.VisitID =t2.VisitID
where t2.Actiondateandtime in (select  max(Actiondateandtime )
                               from TableB
                               group by VisitID)
```

check this fiddle    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4f80/2

Comment: This could work, but it would be better if it were `joined` or `correlated` with the `visitid`.  As is, if there are duplicate dates, this could return false positives.

Comment: Hi Dhaval. Thank you. I got the idea and the code works good.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to `join` the table back to itself using the `max` aggregate to get the max date grouped by visitid:

```
select a.visitid, a.visittitle, a.conclusion, b.refid, b.actiondateandtime
from tablea a 
  join tableb b on a.visitid = b.visitid
  join (
    select visitid, max(actiondateandtime) actiondateandtime
    from tableb 
    group by visitid
    ) c on b.visitid = c.visitid and b.actiondateandtime = c.actiondateandtime
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c34b1f/2)